# How to check battery drain on Aquaris E5

Tags: battery, aquaris

I have my Ubuntu Aquaris about a year. In the beginning there were some battery problems, but everything was fixed.

A few days from now my battery drains really fast (from 70% to 10% overnight). I didn't change anything and it didn't happen immediately after OTA-9.

So I have no idea what's wrong. Is there a way to check what drains the battery? Or are there people with the same problem?